# GitHub Pages に公開したブログが白い画面のままになる

Tags: node.js, github, angular, github-pages

GitHub Pagesとhexoを使ってブログサイトを作ろうと思っているのですが、ローカルでテストした時にはちゃんとサイト全体が機能するのに、GitHubにアップロードしサーバーが更新されてそのページを見ると白い画面になっています。
いろいろな直し方を調べたのですが解決策が見つからず質問させていただきました。

問題が起こっているブログのレポジトリ：
https://github.com/suzume-lab/blog-beta.github.io

使っているthemeのレポジトリ：
https://github.com/ikeq/hexo-theme-inside

お手数をおかけしてしまいますがだれか詳しい方がいれば教えていただきたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scriptタグのsrcなどが`/`で始まっていますが、これだとドメイン直下から参照するようになっているみたいです。`./`にすると直ると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます<(_ _)>　まだブログを作るのは初めてなので少し不安がありお聞きしたいのですがscriptタグなどというのは　blog.github.io/index.html　のもののことでしょうか？　度重なる質問申し訳ございませんもしできれば回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 今ご指摘の通りサイトを変更したところ無事に動作できました。　今回は本当にありがとうございました<(_ _)>